# How to detect if the audio is currently playing on an Android phone speaker?

Tags: android, speaker

I need to have some custom behavior in my app when the audio playback is done on the device speaker (not a wired headphone and not a BlueTooth receiver).
To do so I'm doing the following

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) service.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    isSpeakerPhoneOn = audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
```

But isSpeakerPhoneOn is **always** false.
By the way, I'm calling the code after playback is started.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try this

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())
 {
     // do something - or don't
 }
```

Comment: This is returning true even though I'm listening through a BT headset

Comment: do you want to check if the speaker is playing or if the BT headset is playing ?

Comment: I want to know if there's some sound coming out of the phone speakers

Comment: yeah isMusicActive() should works perfectly ! for the phone speaker... I don't know if it works with BT headset

Comment: it returns true during playback, no matter if it's routed through a BT receiver

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what clearly you want, could you describe that precisely, such that I can help

Comment: I just want to know when my playback is done through the device speaker